# BjyAuthorize settings file connect with database table

Tags: zend-framework2, acl, bjyauthorize

I am using BjyAuthorize to control access in my project.

Everything working as expected with hard coded settings in **module.bjyauthorize.global.php** file. But my requirement is to set users dynamically and assign their user levels dynamically.

So I want to connect this file to DB tables some how and dynamically load settings. Please someone help me to get my thing done

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own Providers or Guards that will load the settings from the database.
See `BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb` or `BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set settings in the Module class.

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $authorizeService = $serviceManager->get('BjyAuthorize\Service\Authorize');
        // settings
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
In this way, do I need to add this code to each and every module seperately..?

Comment: Depending on what exactly to configure. You can set all settings in your `Application` module.

Comment: Thank you. Lets say now I wanna set "guards"( or "rule_providers","resource_providers" or any appeared in _module.bjyauthorize.global.php_) in this manner. How to approach..?

Comment: Maybe I'm a little misunderstood the question. This version can also be, but better look at my other answer.